# ECDH library in C?

Tags: c, encryption, open-source

I've had success using [SJCL](http://crypto.stanford.edu/sjcl/) for [ECDH](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elliptic_curve_Diffie%E2%80%93Hellman), but that's Javascript, and I need a C port. I've found C ports, but they're either part of some giant project, or some specialized ECDH that is not compatible with generic ECDH like SJCL. I need a minimal open-source ECDH C implementation for a microprocessor project. I'd rather not make it myself. Any suggestions?

Comment: You might want to list what C ports you've already looked at and rejected.  OpenSSL does ECDH.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If GPL is ok, there's [SECCURE](http://point-at-infinity.org/seccure/)

I haven't used it personally but did stumble upon it couple of months ago when evaluating my options for a pet project.